# PhoneGap - Resources found for language(s) 'en,eu' but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-US'

Tags: xml, cordova, flask, progressive-web-apps, phonegap

Good morning,
I'm trying to build a PWA application from my Flask project. I implemented internationalization in it, but when it comes to build the application, this is the error I get on PhoneGap.

```
Building project: C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
    Configuration : debug
    Platform      : x86
  Patching 10 in prebuild event...
  Injected base.js reference to the www/index.html
  Removing /( *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.WinJS.2.0\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/ from www/index.html
  Removing /( *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/ from www/index.html
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: CPYTHON-36 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: CPYTHON-37 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: CPYTHON-37 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: CPYTHON-36 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: CPYTHON-37 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: CPYTHON-37 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: CPYTHON-37 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: CPYTHON-36 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: CPYTHON-37 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00522: Resources found for language(s) 'en,eu' but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-US'. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899 [C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
  CordovaApp.Windows10 -> C:\Cygwin64\tmp\gimlet\4104270\project\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.0_x86_debug_Test\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.0_x86_debug.appx
```

I don't know how to fix it. I want my default language to be Spanish, but I don't know where to change it. If anyone could help I'd be grateful. This is my config.xml if any more information is required. (I hid the names manually)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id="com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode="10"
        version="1.0.0">
   <name>App</name>
   <description>
       Description
   </description>
   <author href="https://xxxxx.yyy" email= "email@domain.com">
       Name Surname
   </author>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Busto from you error I find this link a link:

They say:

> Resources found for language(s) '<language(s)>' but no resources found
> for default language(s): '<language(s)>'. Change the default language
> or qualify resources with the default language. This warning is
> displayed when MakePri.exe or MSBuild discovers files or string
> resources for a given named resource that appear to be marked with
> language qualifiers, but no candidate is found for a default language.
> The process for using qualifiers in file and folder names is described
> in Tailor your resources for language, scale, and other qualifiers. A
> file or folder may have a language name in it, but no resources are
> discovered that are qualified for the exact default language. For
> example, if a project uses "en-US" as the default language and has a
> file named "de/logo.png", but does not have any files that are marked
> with the default language "en-US", this warning will appear. In order
> to remove this warning, either file(s) or string resource(s) should be
> qualified with the default language, or the default language should be
> changed. To change the default language, with your solution open in
> Visual Studio, open Package.appxmanifest. On the Application tab,
> confirm that the Default language is set appropriately (for example,
> "en" or "en-US").

See here more about this error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/compile-resources-manually-with-makepri#makepriexe-warnings-and-error-messages